# Django + Django Rest Framework: get correct related objects on intermediate model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have an intermediate model with the following fields:

```
class UserSkill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_skills')
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

As you can see, it has two foreign keys, one to the auth user and one to another table called **skill**.

I am trying to get all Skills assigned to an specific user, so I do the following **get_queryset** in my ViewSet:

```
class AssignedSkillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Skill.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AssignedSkillSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Skill.objects.filter(user_skills__user=user, user_skills_user__disabled=False))
```

Now, I also need to include the intermediate model information in the API, which I can access trough **users_skills** related name in DRF's Serializer, as follows:

```
class AssignedSkillSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        fields = [
            'id',
            'url',
            'title',
            'description',
            'user_skills',
        ]
```

But when I try to get that information it returns **ALL** user_skills related to the assigned skill, no matter if they are assigned to other users. I need the related model information only for that user and that skill.

**For Example:**
If I have a skill named **Math**, and a user named **Maria**

```
related_skills = Skill.objects.filter(user_skills__user=user, user_skills_user__disabled=False)).user_skills.all()
```

The above code will return:

```
[
  <UserSkill: Math+Jenniffer>,
  <UserSkill: Math+Gabriel>,
  <UserSkill: Math+John>,
  <UserSkill: Math+Maria>,
]
```

I only need to get the item **<UserSkill: Math+Maria>**. The list is not ordered in any way so getting the last item on the list does not work in all cases.

I know there is something I'm probably missing. I appreciate any help or clues you people can give me.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to use a [**`Prefetch`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object with a custom queryset, that uses the same filters as your main queryset like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user

    return Skill.objects.filter(
        user_skills__user=user, 
        user_skills__user__disabled=False,
    ).prefetch_related(
        "user_skills",
        queryset=UserSkill.objects.filter(
            user=user, 
            user__disabled=False,
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you do the filter:

```
Skill.objects.filter(
user_skills__user=user,   #condition_1
user_skills_user__disabled=False, #condition_2
).user_skills.all()
```

You already did a query related to the `UserSkill` model. Because the filter is done in the `Skill` model and the #condition_1 (`user_skills__user=user`) uses the information from the `UserSkill` model to filter by users. But when you do `.user_skills.all()` at the end of the query you are overring the filter with all the data from the UserSkill model.

To get a list of UserSkill instances from the filter you could try:

```
UserSkill.objects.filter(
user="Maria", 
skill="Math",
)
```

Comment: Hi Claudius. Thanks for your answer. I do not do a "user_skills.all()" query, that was an example. I just get the data from the related field in the serializer. and I don't want to do a second query for userSkills because I am pre-fetching that information already in the first queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help
serializers.py

```
class SkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        fields = ['id', ...]

class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    skill_detail = SkillSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserSkill
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'skill_detail']
```

views.py

```
class AssignedSkillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserSkill.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSkillSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return UserSkill.objects.filter(user=user, disabled=False))
```